# Multiple domains one sign on (without logging in to each one)

Tags: single-sign-on

I have been asked to oversee the development of a handful of sites. The people running the show want it so that if you sign onto one of the sites, then you are automatically signed onto the rest of them.

One of my buddies who is a great programmer says there is no safe way to do this, is he right?

I had an idea that the main site (parent site) could host the daughter sites as sub domains, with each site having its own unique domain name.

What do you think?

Comment: Voted down twice and no answers? Nice community.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. However, it won't be a trivial solution but will be a very expensive project that requires an extensive set of skills. Companies typically try to achieve this by establishing internal solutions themselves but tend to fail as complexity increases.

What you are trying to accomplished can also be done as a service. You may want to take a look at the following webpage:

http://www.covisint.com/web/guest/about-identity-services

Hope that helps!